# Trying to change all tabs to a set number of spaces, K&R Exercise 1-20

Tags: c

I have a solution that I'm relatively sure should work, however, when I run it given an input such as:

```
This is\ta test.
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I get an output like this:

```
This is    
^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is the solution I've written, and I'm almost certain it should work; it makes sense logically, but there's something that just isn't adding up.

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define MAX_SIZE 1000
#define TAB_STOP 4

char line[MAX_SIZE];
int getline_(void);

int main()
{
  int c, len;
  extern char longest[];

  while ((len = getline_()) > 0)
    printf("Line: %s", line);

  return 0;
}

int getline_(void)
{
  int chr, index;
  extern char line[];
  int x;

  for (index = 0; index < (MAX_SIZE - 1)
         && ((chr = getchar()) != EOF) && chr != '\n'; ++index) {
    if (chr == '\t') {
      for (x = 0; x < TAB_STOP && index < MAX_SIZE - 5; ++x) {
        line[index + x] = ' ';
        printf("%d\n", index);
      }
      index = index + x;
    }
    else
      line[index] = chr;
  }
  if (chr == '\n') {
    line[index] = chr;
    ++index;
  }

  line[index] = '\0';
  return index;
}
```

Comment: `\t` is stored as a single character and not actually 4 seperate characters. You should only blank out one character.

Comment: @kaylum shouldn't it still work regardless? The wording of the exercise is a bit strange, but I think part of it is replacing '\t' with n blank spaces.

for reference:
Write a program detab that replaces tabs in the input with the proper number of blanks to space to the next tab stop. Assume a fixed set of tab stops, say every n columns. Should n be a variable or a symbolic parameter?

Comment: @kaylum in my case, `\t` is strored in two characters: "\" (asccii : 92) and "t"

Comment: @Landstalker I interpreted the question as saying that the file has a tab character. Tab is an escape character. Escape characters are represented with a \ prefix but when stored they are a single character. The ascii for `\t` is 9. Refer to the [ascii man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html)

Comment: @kaylum yes i understand, but in this program, the test `if (chr == '\t')` is never reached

Comment: @Landstalker Ok, but what does that have to do with the fact that `\t` is stored as a single char?

Comment: @kaylum if `\t` is interpreted as a single character, the test `if (chr == '\t')` is correct and therefore the program is correct. Otherwise, the test is not correct and therefore the program is not correct.

Comment: @Landstalker I think the question is a bit unclear. Does the file really have "\" and "t" or does it have a real tab (and is only shown as "\t" to indicate there is a tab). If the former then your interpretation is correct. I'm assuming the latter (but maybe I'm wrong - question isn't clear).

Comment: @kaylum I also did not understand how the owner of the program intends to enter the tabulation, because by reading his post (input: **This is\ta test.**), I understood that he wants to enter it in two characters "\" and "t"

Comment: `extern char longest[];` is weird, especially as it isn’t used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case where `chr == '\t'` you are incrementing `index` twice:

- the first time with `index = index + x;`
- the second time within the for statement `++index`

An easy, dirty, trick would be to change the first increment to `index = index + x - 1;`.

I fully agree with @Sneftel that it would be better to only increment `index` with the correct value. That means *not* increment it within a for statement. And do the increment once in each alternative of the `if`… `else` blocks with the right value.

Comment: Agreed with the diagnosis, but IMO it's *much* better to put the increment in the `if` and `else` blocks than to pre-correct for it in `else`. It makes termination conditions easier to think about, and the bare `;` at the end of the for statement is a clear and idiomatic warning that special stuff is going on with the iteration.

Comment: @Sneftel I agree, that's why I said it's a dirty trick. Edited to mention this.

Comment: @Sneftel What do you mean by putting the increment in the `if` and `else` blocks? As in like, put it in the condition statement? Ohh, I see. Nevermind; just saw the edit.